# Agrupar e somar valores de cada grupo de um array php laravel

Tags: php, array, laravel

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2477 (4) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "in"
      ["category"]=>
      string(24) "Tratamento Odontológico"
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "333.33333333333"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#2478 (4) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "in"
      ["category"]=>
      string(24) "Tratamento Odontológico"
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "333.33333333333"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#2479 (4) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "in"
      ["category"]=>
      string(24) "Tratamento Odontológico"
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "333.33333333333"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(stdClass)#2480 (4) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "in"
      ["category"]=>
      string(24) "Tratamento Odontológico"
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "333.33333333333"
    }
    [4]=>
    object(stdClass)#2481 (4) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "in"
      ["category"]=>
      string(24) "Tratamento Odontológico"
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "333.33333333333"
    }
    [5]=>
    object(stdClass)#2482 (4) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "out"
      ["category"]=>
      string(24) "Contabilidade"
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "85.106382978723"
    }
    [6]=>
    object(stdClass)#2483 (4) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "in"
      ["category"]=>
      string(24) "Celular"
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "100"
    }
    [7]=>
    object(stdClass)#2484 (4) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "in"
      ["category"]=>
      string(24) "Celular"
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "100"
    }
    [8]=>
    object(stdClass)#2485 (4) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "in"
      ["category"]=>
      string(24) "Celular"
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "100"
    }
}
```

Preciso agrupar o campo category pra que seja retornado apenas 1 item de cada tipo de categoria diferente e somar os valores de cada categoria. Isso precisa retornar, por exemplo:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2477 (4) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "in"
    ["category"]=>
    string(24) "Tratamento Odontológico"
    ["value"]=>
    string(16) "1666,666666667"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2478 (4) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "out"
    ["category"]=>
    string(24) "Contabilidade"
    ["value"]=>
    string(15) "85.106382978723"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#2479 (4) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "in"
    ["category"]=>
    string(24) "Celular"
    ["value"]=>
    string(15) "300"
  }
}
```

Eu já pesquisei e tentei várias formas de fazer isso, mas realmente to muito perdido e preciso de ajuda com isso, obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá

Podes usar collections
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

```
//simular valores
$lista = []; 

    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $item = new stdClass();
        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            $item->category = "Tratamento Odontológico";
            $item->value = 111;
        } else {
            $item->category = "Contabilidade";
            $item->value = 222;
        }

        $lista[] = $item;
    }


    //criar uma Collection com base no array, agrupar por category numa nova Collection, criar uma nova Collection com os items agrupados por categoria com o valor resultante da soma desses items.

    $colecao = collect($lista)->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->category;
    })->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->sum('value');
    });
```

**Resultado**

```
Collection {#515 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "Tratamento Odontológico" => 5550
    "Contabilidade" => 11100
  ]
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! É que eu sou novo com Laravel então não conhecia o "Collections", só precisei usar do $colecao pra baixo e substituir o $lista e $item pela variável que recebe os dados do banco, daí fez exatamente o que eu precisava! Muito obrigado mesmo!!